# How to validate the url in javascript?

Tags: javascript, validation, url

I have one input type to enter the url and one select tag to choose the url type.
Now I want to check if selected type and entered url matches or not, like one should not be able to input the instagram url and select the url type as facebook.

So I want to validate this. I tried to use one function to validate and it is working fine to validate the url but I want to also validate for facebook and instagram if it is photos url or video url.

Right now it commonly validates for facebook.com.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Post</title>
</head>
<body>

<form class="postForm" id="postForm" method="post" action="addPost.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Please add the details below </legend>
        <p>

        <div id="link" style="display: none">

        <p>
            <label for="url">URL (required)</label>
            <input id="url" type="url" name="url" required>
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="urlType">Select Url Type :(required)</label>
            <select name="urlType" id="urlType">
                <option value="">Select Url Type...</option>
        <!--        <option value="0">Server Image</option>
                <option value="1">Server Video</option>-->
                <option value="2">YouTube Video</option>
                <option value="3">Vimeo Video</option>
                <option value="4">Facebook Image</option>
                <option value="5">Facebook Video</option>
                <option value="6">Instagram Image</option>
                <option value="7">Instagram Video</option>
                <option value="-1">Other</option>
            </select>
        </p>

        </div>

        <div id="filediv" style="display: none">

            Select file to upload:
            <br><br>
            <input name="file" type="file" id="fileToUpload"><br><br>

        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="hidden" name="action_type" id="action_type_id"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="id" id="p_id"/>

           <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
        </p>
    </fieldset>

    <div class="result" id="result"></div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $('#postForm').validate({ // initialize the plugin
            rules: {
                title: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength : 2
                },
                url: {
                    required: true
                },
                desc: {
                    required : true,
                    minlength : 2
                },
                keywords : {
                    required : true,
                    minlength : 2
                },
                urlType :
                    {
                        required : true
                    },
                postType :
                    {
                        required : true
                    },
                category :
                    {
                        required : true
                    },
                 file :
                     {
                         required : true
                     }
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo

                var url = document.getElementById('urlType').value;

                if(validate_url(document.getElementById('url').value) == 'facebook' && url != 4)
                {
                    alert('Please enter valid facebook image url or select valid url type.');
                }
                else if(validate_url(document.getElementById('url').value) == 'facebook' && url != 5)
                {
                    alert('Please enter valid facebook video url or select valid url type.');
                }
                else if(validate_url(document.getElementById('url').value) == 'instagram' && url != 6)
                {
                    alert('Please enter valid instagram image url or select valid url type.');
                }
                else if(validate_url(document.getElementById('url').value) == 'instagram' && url != 7)
                {
                    alert('Please enter valid instagram video url or select valid url type.');
                }
                else if(validate_url(document.getElementById('url').value) == 'vimeo' && url != 3)
                {
                    alert('Please enter valid vimeo video url or select valid url type.');
                }
                else if(validate_url(document.getElementById('url').value) == 'youtube' && url != 2)
                {
                    alert('Please enter valid youtube video url or select valid url type.');
                }
                else {
                    userAction('add');
                }
            }
        });


        function userAction(type,id){

            var statusArr = {add:"added",edit:"updated",delete:"deleted"};

            if (type == 'add') {

                $('#action_type_id').val(type);
                $('#p_id').val(id);
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'addPost.php',
                data: $('#postForm').serialize(),
                success:function(report){
                    // replace data to report
                    $(".result").html(report);

                    $("#postForm").trigger('reset');
                }
            });
        }


        function validate_url(url)
        {
            if (/^(https?:\/\/)?((w{3}\.)?)facebook.com\/.*/i.test(url))
                return 'facebook';

            if (/^(https?:\/\/)?((w{3}\.)?)instagram.com\/.*/i.test(url))
                return 'instagram';

            if (/^(https?:\/\/)?((w{3}\.)?)vimeo.com\/.*/i.test(url))
                return 'vimeo';

            if (/^(https?:\/\/)?((w{3}\.)?)youtube.com\/.*/i.test(url))
                return 'youtube';

            return 'unknown';
        }

    </script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I validate if the link is for facebook image,facebook video or instagram image, instagram video?

Please help.. Thank you.

Comment: when you say `validate if the link is for facebook image,facebook video`... do you mean if its a video or image hosted by Facebook? Facebook has lots of CDNs so you'd have to validate a variety of URL patterns and you can't guarantee they will stay the same. i.e. `scontent.fsnc1-1.fna.fbcdn.net` is a potential domain

Comment: yes want to validate if it is a facebook video or image @aug

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and looked at a variety of different url formations and here are some:

Facebook Video

`https://video.fsnc1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/*.mp4`

Facebook Image

`https://scontent.fsnc1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/*.jpg`

Instagram Video

`https://instagram.fsnc1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/*.mp4`

Instagram Image

`https://instagram.fsnc1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/*.jpg`

For regex if you wanted to see if they were hosted by Facebook in general, you could validate if the domain was `fbcdn.net`. For instagram, it seems all their assets are prefixed in the subdomain `instagram.*.fbcdn.net`

Note that the `fsnc1-1.fna` is likely related to where the CDN is requesting the nearest server and this can change. For example, doing a Webpage Test from Brazil shows assets coming from `scontent-gru2-2.xx.fbcdn.net` so you'll want your regex to be dynamic for that.

Hope this helps.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/OccupyDemocrats/videos/1497544510338598/  if the  video url is like this? and facebook image like this https://www.facebook.com/facebook/photos/a.376995711728.190761.20531316728/10154878491331729/?type=3&theater